# Show label on only top bar in stacked bar chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am working on making a stacked bar chart in HTML using JS and Chart.js. For this chart, I don't want axes or multiple stacked bars (just one). I figured out how to do all of that and the custom labels, but I only want the label to show in the top bar (red bar in this example). How can I go about only displaying the label in the top bar? I'm not really sure how the formatter thing works, I just copy and pasted it in and it displays the info that I was looking for.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-8 offset-2 my-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                Stacked Bar Chart in Chart JS
                <hr>
                <canvas id="barchart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>

<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('barchart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: [1],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Hypo',
          data: [12],
          backgroundColor: [
              'red',
          ],
          borderColor: [
              'red',
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
      }, {
          label: 'Hyper',
          data: [12],
          backgroundColor: [
              'orange',
          ],
          borderColor: [
              'orange',
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  },
  options: {
      plugins: {
          legend: {
              display: false
          },
          datalabels: {
              color: 'black', 
              labels: {
                  title: {
                      font: {
                          family: "sans-serif",
                          size: 100,
                          weight: 'bold'
                      }
                  }
              },
              formatter: function(value, context) {
                  return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
              }
          }
      },
      scales: {
          x: {
              stacked: true,
              display: false,
          },
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              stacked: true,
              display: false,
          },
      }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the answer to this myself. I changed the formatter function to this:

```
formatter: function(value, context) {
   return context.datasetIndex == 1 ? context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex] : ' ';
}
```